# What is an intuitive explanation of rotation in red-black trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree

Quoting from CLRS
When we do a left rotation
on a node x, we assume that its right child y is not T.nil; x may be any node in
the tree whose right child is not T.nil. The left rotation “pivots” around the link
from x to y. It makes y the new root of the subtree, with x as y’s left child and y’s left child as x’s right child.

I understand the above passage and can understand what is happening here.
But how does left rotation produces below.

[image]
Where is the rotation part? What thing rotated to what?
Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like you want to read the very [basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation). After that, keep in mind that rotations preserve properties of trees; including, but probably not limited to, order of elements, tree height, and other properties specific to each type of tree: for [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties) that'd be #4.

Answer (score 0):

The rotations have the effect of exchanging the depths of the subtrees *alpha* and *gamma*, in order to improve balancing. The depth of *beta* remains unchanged.